# How do I know what page is displayed when using snapToInterval or pagingEnabled in a scrollView?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am developing one app that I am rendering images horizontally using a *scrollView* and I would like to have one pagination indicator like Instagram's. In other words, I want to indicate on the bottom of my scrollView the page by changing the color of some circles.

I am using a *scrollView* and I have the option to use the *pagingEnabled* or *snapToInterval*, but using both there is no way to know what page is being displayed, so I can not create the pagination indicator because I need this information.

One way that I managed to do it was using the *onScroll* prop and reading the actual x offset, dividing it by the screen width and rounding it up I know what image is being displayed, but as the *onScroll* prop executes each frame, it makes the application very slow, resulting in a delay of almost 1 sec after the page is scrolled and the value (index of the image displayed) is calculated. That is the code:

```
...
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
return (
         <ScrollView
          horizontal
          pagingEnabled
          onScroll={(event) =>
            setIndex(
              Math.floor(
                (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x + 0.1) /
                  width
              )
            )
          }
        >
          <Images/>
        </ScrollView>
)
```

If I could execute one function when the pagination animation happens forward and backward, it would be much easier and would solve the problem completely. There is any or better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library.

> react-native-snap-carousel

Here you can see the documentation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snap-carousel